# Why is a random variable being a deterministic function of another random variable mean that it is in the sigma algebra of the other variables?

Tags: random-variable, measure-theory, sigma-algebra

Specifically, I'm learning about martingales in class right now.
Given random variables $T$, $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$, textbook that I'm reading draws an equivalence between the statement that the indicator of the event $T\leq n$ is a function of $X_0, X_1, \ldots, X_n$ and the statement that $\{T\leq n\}\in \sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$.
I'm not sure why this holds.

Is it true in general that if $Y = g(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ for some deterministic $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ that any Borel set $B$ satisfies $Y^{-1}(B)\in\sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$?

Comment: What assumptions are you making about a "deterministic" $g$?  One would hope that at a minimum it is measurable!

Comment: Yes $g$ is measurable. Also these variables are over the same probability space.

Comment: Yes this is true. This is [Doob-Dynkin's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%E2%80%93Dynkin_lemma).